# Reference to any character in a string::string in C++

Tags: c++, string, reference

I want the reference to the `i` th character of a string `name`.

I couldn't a find a function for the same.

Comment: You want the address in memory or you want to retrieve the character at the `i`th index?

Comment: `auto& ch = name.operator[](i);` or more commonly `auto& ch = name[i];`

Comment: `std::string::operator[](size_t i)` returns a reference to the character of index `i`

Comment: @smac89 Consider `name` was an int array, then `name+i`, would provide me the address of the `i` th character position. Similarly, for the case of string::string, I want to know which operator/function would help to retrieve the address in memory of the `i` th character.

Comment: @Thope 'reference to' and 'address of' mean two different things `s[i]` gives you the reference, there isn't a single function that gives you the address but `&s[i]` works if you will accept an expression.

Comment: @john that cleared things up, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the sort of question that begs for a good C++ reference. Look up `std::string` in that reference (which might redirect you to the more general `std::basic_string`), then look for a member function that lets you access characters (or "elements" as a more general term).

For example, [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) lists the member functions of `basic_string` grouped by the kind of functionality provided. The first two functions listed in the "element access" group, `at()` and `operator[]`, provide access to the specified character. Either of the following two expressions will provide a reference to the `i`th character of a string `name`.

- `name.at(i)`
- `name[i]`

Alternatively, you could use pointer arithmetic with `data()` or `c_str()`, but the resulting expressions tend to be messier. Stick with simple as long as simple is adequate.

Answer (score -1):

There isn’t a function. Just `auto &ref = str[i]`

Comment: That is actually calling one of the two member functions: [`std::basic_string<CharT,Traits,Allocator>::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at)

Comment: Are you claiming that [`std::string::at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/at) is not a function?

Comment: I thank both of the clarifications provided as accurate and detailed answers as per the standard and the specifics of the implementation details. However, I provided my answer in the spirit that would help the person who asked it, not in terms of `noexcept`, `const`, whether it was possible to get an rvalue with strategic use of `std::launder` to not invalidate the underlying store. Sometimes folk just want to get stuff done.

Comment: @RichL Uh... what? Who said anything about `noexcept`, `const`, or `std::launder`? I was challenging your claim that there isn't a function. There **is** a function. Just use `auto &ref = str.at(i)` and get stuff done.

Comment: @RichL I can sympathize in that some people are overly harsh and nitpicky about answers on this site. I agree it could be considered nitpicky to point out that `operator[]` is a function even though its use does not look like a function call. However, the use of `at()` does look like a function call, and it serves the same role as `operator[]` as far as this question is concerned. You made a flat-out wrong claim even if one is lax with definitions.